# iText(Sharp) - Keeping section heading with first line of text causes unpleasant bookmarks

Tags: c#, itext

I'm creating a PDF document using Chapter and Section objects so I get the spiffy tree-structure bookmarks and that's great, but I also want to apply "keep with next" to the chapter and section headings so the first paragraph after the heading doesn't get pushed to a separate page from the heading.

I'm doing this by defining each section with a paragraph that I hang onto:

```
void AddSection(Section parentSection, string newSectionTitle)
{
   m_heading = new Paragraph(new Chunk(newSectionTitle));
   m_section = parentSection.AddSection(indentation, m_heading);
}
```

and then when I add the first chunk to that section, I add it to that heading:

```
void AddTextToSection(string text)
{
   if (m_heading != null)
   {
      m_heading.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
      m_heading.Add(new Chunk(text));
      m_heading = null;
   }
   else
   {
      m_section.Add(new Chunk(text));
   }
}
```

That works great EXCEPT that the bookmark then contains the heading PLUS the first paragraph.

Is there a way to tell a Chapter or Section that it should display text X in the body of the document, but define the bookmark using text Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Section has a property named BookmarkTitle which, if set, specifies the text that will be used for the bookmark title.

So after I create the Section, but before I start adding text to it (via my AddTextToSection() function), I extract the text from m_section.Title.Chunks and set it into m_section.BookmarkTitle.